# editing wordpress custom header php file

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I am using an open source theme for a wordpress website. While most of the site is done, I am having trouble adding a second slogan area to our site.

Additionally, I am attempting to modify **customer_header.php** to make the front page showcase appear on all pages as well.

Currently the home page is the only page displaying the header showcase and only has two lines of text. The following is the php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Sample implementation of the Custom Header feature.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers
 *
 * @package refur
 */

class refur_custom_header {

    /**
     * A reference to an instance of this class.
     *
     * @var object
     */
    private static $instance = null;

    /**
     * Default header settings array
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $default_settings = array();

    /**
     * Holder for active showcase trigger
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $is_showcase = null;

    function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'body_class', array( $this, 'add_body_classes' ) );
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'custom_header_setup' ) );
        add_action( 'refur_header_showcase', array( $this, 'public_callback' ) );
        add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'header_settings' ) );

        $this->default_settings = array(
            'header_mask_color'   => '#000000',
            'header_mask_fill'    => 50,
            'header_slogan_title' => __( 'Your Awesome Blog', 'refur' ),
            'header_slogan_text'  => __( 'Just a few words why you blog is so awesome', 'refur' ),
            'header_button_text'  => __( 'Call to action', 'refur' ),
            'header_button_url'   => '#'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Set up the WordPress core custom header feature.
     *
     * @uses refur_header_style()
     * @uses refur_admin_header_style()
     * @uses refur_admin_header_image()
     */
    function custom_header_setup() {
        add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'refur_custom_header_args', array(
            'default-image'          => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header-image.png',
            'default-text-color'     => 'ffffff',
            'width'                  => 2000,
            'height'                 => 765,
            'flex-height'            => true,
            'wp-head-callback'       => array( $this, 'header_style' ),
            'admin-head-callback'    => array( $this, 'admin_header_style' ),
            'admin-preview-callback' => array( $this, 'admin_header_image' ),
        ) ) );
    }

    /**
     * Register additional setting for header section
     *
     * @param  object $wp_customize customizer object
     * @return void
     */
    function header_settings( $wp_customize ) {

        $wp_customize->add_setting('refur[header_mask_color]', array(
                'default'           => $this->default_settings['header_mask_color'],
                'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
                'type'              => 'theme_mod',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'refur_header_mask_color', array(
                'label'    => __( 'Image Mask Color', 'refur' ),
                'section'  => 'header_image',
                'settings' => 'refur[header_mask_color]',
        )));

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'refur[header_mask_fill]', array(
                'default'           => $this->default_settings['header_mask_fill'],
                'type'              => 'theme_mod',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'refur_sanitize_num',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'refur_header_mask_fill', array(
                'label'       => __( 'Image mask fill level', 'refur' ),
                'section'     => 'header_image',
                'settings'    => 'refur[header_mask_fill]',
                'type'        => 'number',
                'input_attrs' => array(
                    'min'  => 0,
                    'max'  => 100,
                    'step' => 1,
                ),
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'refur[header_slogan_title]', array(
                'default'           => $this->default_settings['header_slogan_title'],
                'type'              => 'theme_mod',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
        ) );
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'refur_header_slogan_title', array(
                'label'       => __( 'Header slogan title', 'refur' ),
                'section'     => 'header_image',
                'settings'    => 'refur[header_slogan_title]',
                'type'        => 'text',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'refur[header_slogan_text]', array(
                'default'           => $this->default_settings['header_slogan_text'],
                'type'              => 'theme_mod',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
        ) );
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'refur_header_slogan_text', array(
                'label'       => __( 'Header slogan description', 'refur' ),
                'section'     => 'header_image',
                'settings'    => 'refur[header_slogan_text]',
                'type'        => 'text',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'refur[header_button_text]', array(
                'default'           => $this->default_settings['header_button_text'],
                'type'              => 'theme_mod',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
        ) );
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'refur_header_button_text', array(
                'label'       => __( 'Header button text (leave empty to remove button)', 'refur' ),
                'section'     => 'header_image',
                'settings'    => 'refur[header_button_text]',
                'type'        => 'text',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'refur[header_button_url]', array(
                'default'           => $this->default_settings['header_button_url'],
                'type'              => 'theme_mod',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'refur_sanitize_url',
        ) );
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'refur_header_button_url', array(
                'label'       => __( 'Header button URL', 'refur' ),
                'section'     => 'header_image',
                'settings'    => 'refur[header_button_url]',
                'type'        => 'text',
        ) );
    }

    /**
     * Custom header image markup displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.
     *
     * @see custom_header_setup().
     */
    function admin_header_image() {
    ?>
        <div id="headimg">
            <h1 class="displaying-header-text">
                <a id="name" style="<?php echo esc_attr( 'color: #' . get_header_textcolor() ); ?>" onclick="return false;" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
            </h1>
            <div class="displaying-header-text" id="desc" style="<?php echo esc_attr( 'color: #' . get_header_textcolor() ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></div>
            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }

    /**
     * Public output for header image
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function public_callback() {

        $custom_callback = apply_filters( 'refur_custom_header_showcase_callback', false );

        if ( false !== $custom_callback ) {
            echo $custom_callback;
            return true;
        }

        $this->open_image_wrap();
        $this->show_image();
        $this->show_slogan();
        $this->close_image_wrap();

    }

    /**
     * Open HTML wrapper for header image block
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function open_image_wrap() {

        $subpage = '';

        if ( ! $this->is_showcase() ) {
            $subpage = ' is-subpage';
        }

        echo '<div class="header-showcase' . $subpage . '">';
    }

    public function show_image() {
        $image = get_header_image();
        $data  = get_custom_header();
        $alt   = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

        if ( ! $image ) {
            return;
        }

        printf(
            '<img src="%s" class="header-showcase_img" alt="%s" width="%s" height="%s">',
            $image, $alt, $data->width, $data->height
        );
    }

    /**
     * Show header showcase content
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function show_slogan() {

        if ( ! $this->is_showcase() ) {
            return;
        }

        $title = refur_get_option( 'header_slogan_title', $this->default_settings['header_slogan_title'] );
        $text  = refur_get_option( 'header_slogan_text', $this->default_settings['header_slogan_text'] );
        ?>
        <div class="header-showcase_content">
            <div class="container">
                <?php if ( $title || $text ) : ?>
                <div class="header-showcase_slogan">
                    <?php if ( $title ) : ?>
                    <div class="header-showcase_title"><?php
                        echo wp_kses( $title, wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) );
                    ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ( $text ) : ?>
                    <div class="header-showcase_text"><?php
                        echo wp_kses( $text, wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) );
                    ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $this->show_button(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Show header showcase call to action button
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function show_button() {

        $text = refur_get_option( 'header_button_text', $this->default_settings['header_button_text'] );
        $url  = refur_get_option( 'header_button_url', $this->default_settings['header_button_url'] );

        if ( ! $text ) {
            return;
        }

        printf( '<a href="%2$s" class="header-showcase_btn">%1$s</a>', esc_textarea( $text ), esc_url( $url ) );

    }

    /**
     * Close HTML wrapper for header image block
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function close_image_wrap() {
        echo '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * Is showcase area visible on current page
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function is_showcase() {

        if ( null !== $this->is_showcase ) {
            return $this->is_showcase;
        }
        $this->is_showcase = ( is_front_page() && ! is_paged() ) ? true : false;
        return $this->is_showcase;
    }

    /**
     * Styles the header image and text displayed on the blog
     *
     * @see custom_header_setup().
     */
    function header_style() {

        // If we get this far, we have custom styles. Let's do this.
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        <?php
            $mask_bg      = refur_get_option( 'header_mask_color', $this->default_settings['header_mask_color'] );
            $mask_opacity = refur_get_option( 'header_mask_fill', $this->default_settings['header_mask_fill'] );
            $mask_opacity = absint( esc_attr( $mask_opacity ) ) / 100;
        ?>
        .header-showcase:after {
            background: <?php echo esc_attr( $mask_bg ); ?>;
            opacity: <?php echo $mask_opacity; ?>;
        }
        </style>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Styles the header image displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.
     *
     * @see custom_header_setup().
     */
    function admin_header_style() {
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .appearance_page_custom-header #headimg {
                border: none;
            }
            #headimg h1,
            #desc {
            }
            #headimg h1 {
            }
            #headimg h1 a {
            }
            #desc {
            }
            #headimg img {
            }
        </style>
    <?php
    }

    /**
     * Header-related body classes
     *
     * @param array $classes
     */
    public function add_body_classes( $classes ) {

        if ( ! get_header_image() ) {
            $classes[] = 'static-header';
        }

        if ( $this->is_showcase() ) {
            $classes[] = 'showcase-active';
        }

        return $classes;

    }

    /**
     * Returns the instance.
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public static function get_instance() {
        // If the single instance hasn't been set, set it now.
        if ( null == self::$instance )
            self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

}

refur_custom_header::get_instance();
```

Comment: First, the bad news:  The customer_header.php is part of the core WordPress installation and it should never be modified by developers. The good news is there is almost certainly an alternative way to accomplish what you want to do.  If you could povide a link to the theme you are using and perhaps the site (if it is live), it would help.

Comment: Ah, okay. I am glad to hear there is an alternative though. Thank you.

http://servicemygarage.com/ is the live site

http://www.tefox.net/product/refur/ is the theme site

Comment: So, for clarity,  what you want is for the (lovely) image on the front page to also show on other pages of the site?

Comment: I would like the image, text, and button on that front page to appear on all pages.

I also wanted to add a third line of text before the button.

Comment: Very helpful... well it turns out that the file you linked *is* part of the theme and not (as I had thought) part of core (there *is* a custom-header.php in core, but that wasn't (as you probably already know) it).

Comment: lol no worries, I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part one:  I'm not going to write all the code for you, but you can basically just find all the places in that file where you find `header_slogan_title`, `header_slogan_text`, and `header_button_text` and duplicate them judiciously.

For part two: you're going to want to hack this code in the file you linked to in your question:

```
/**
 * Is showcase area visible on current page
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function is_showcase() {

if ( null !== $this->is_showcase ) {
    return $this->is_showcase;
}
$this->is_showcase = ( is_front_page() && ! is_paged() ) ? true : false;
return $this->is_showcase;
}
```

Most likely you will want to change

```
$this->is_showcase = ( is_front_page() && ! is_paged() ) ? true : false;
```

to

```
$this->is_showcase = is_page();
```

or some other combination of template tags that produces true for the pages you want it to show for and false for the others.

Comment: so i made the changes and unfortunately it did not work.

Would I have to change the 
/**
  * Open HTML wrapper for header image block
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function open_image_wrap() {

  $subpage = '';

  if ( ! $this->is_showcase() ) {
   $subpage = ' is-subpage';
  }

  echo '<div class="header-showcase' . $subpage . '">';
 }

 section as well?

Comment: So, what didn't work?  Does it not show up on the other pages?  One troubleshooting method would be to set it to 'true':  `$this->is_showcase = true`

Comment: neither change worked. it still is not showing up on other pages and a third line of text still isn't available. :(

Let me try the boolean.

Comment: even the $this->is_showcase = true isn't allowing either change to occur

Comment: Huh.  I don't have time to build up a test bed for myself to try this out, but that really surprises me.  Have you made any progress since you last posted?

Comment: No worries, I appreciate all the assistance you've provided so far.
I tried rewriting some other parts of the PHP file, and still no changes have been made. I even waiting a few hours incase there was some kind of delay.

I reached out to the author of the theme to see if they could provide any insight, but no reply yet.